# Accessing specific pages in a controller/view on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to set individual Meta Descriptions and Titles to individual pages in a Ruby on Rails App. It was a previous developers App, that I have been given the task to edit. Also, I am new to Rails and Ruby.

The app has a `controllers/pages_controller.rb` where I was am able to set unique variables for `@descriptionX` and `@title` on some pages (mission and disclaimer), but not for others, such as pet_planning.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = params[:page].humanize
    render params[:page]
  end

  def pet_planning
    @descriptionX = 'pet planning'
    @title = 'pet planning title'
    render :pet_planning
  end        

  def mission
    @title = 'Our Mission Statement'
    @descriptionX = 'Mission Description'
    render :mission
  end

  def disclaimer
    @title = 'Our Disclaimer'
    render :disclaimer
  end

end
```

I think that the `render params[:page]` is where I am getting lost. I'm not 100% sure of what this is doing, or how to use it.

I don't understand why I would be able to control the `@title` and `@description` of `mission` but not `pet_planning` when their `views` are both in the same `/views/pages/` directory. And I can't seem to find any distinction between the two anywhere else in the app.

Also, tried to add `= @title = 'Pet Planning'` in the `/views/pages/pet_planning.html.haml` file. It does change the title, however it also displays at the top of the page content unexpectedly.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify. I am able to control the `@title` and `@description` of most pages. Except for a select few in `/views/pages/` directory. But why would I be able to control the `mission` and `disclaimer` when they are also in the aforementioned directory?

Comment: `render params[:page]` allows an attacker to execute arbitrary code (unless there is sanitisation not shown here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend having a read of the [ActionController guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), which explains how Rails turns a request from the user into a page to render.

Basically, when you send a request, for example

```
GET http://www.example.com/pages/?page=pet_planning
```

then Rails works out what to do with it using the router (the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) explains this in more detail). I would imagine that your app is set up so that the `/pages` route matches to the `PagesController#index` action. You can have a look in your `config/routes.rb` file and/or type `rake routes` at the terminal to see how your routes are set up.

The bit after the question mark in the request is the "query string", and Rails turns this into a `params` hash which, for my example above, would look like `{:page => "pet_planning"}`. Your `index` action looks at that to get the name of the page to render - that's what `render params[:page]` is doing.

I guess that the reason you can modify the variables for some of your pages and not others is that some of them have their own routes - `/pages/mission` uses the `PagesController#mission` action, for example - while certain pages are accessed via the `index` action using the `page` param - `/pages/?page=pet_planning` or possibly `/pages/index.html?page=pet_planning`.

**Update**: Your existing route

```
match 'practice_areas/:page' => 'pages#index', :as => :pages
```

could be broken up into

```
match 'practice_areas/pet_planning' => 'pages#pet_planning' :as => :pet_planning
# etc ...
```

which would correspond to a controller that looks like this

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def pet_planning
    @title = "Pet planning!"
    @description = "Whatever..."
  end
end
```

Your suggestion is close, but because the route format is `"controller_name#action_name"`, you would require multiple controllers that looked like this

```
class PetPlanningController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title = "Pet planning!"
    @description = "..."
  end
end
```

and you would have to move your views from `app/views/pages/pet_planning.html.haml` to `app/views/pet_planning/index.html.haml`. So it's probably not quite what you want.

Note that there might be a better way to tackle the problem than splitting everything up into separate actions, if all you are doing differently in each one is customising the title and description. For example, you could use a hash that maps your page name to its corresponding information:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  PAGE_INFO = {
    "pet_planning" => ["Pet planning!", "Whatever..."],
    "other_page" => ["Title", "Description"],
    # ...
  }

  def index
    page_name = params[:page]
    @title, @description = PAGE_INFO[page_name]
    render page_name 
  end
end
```

Comment: You are correct about the routes, and I read through both documents but still am having some trouble. In my `routes.rb` file I found 

`match 'practice_areas/:page' => 'pages#index', :as => :pages` 

and

`match 'mission' => 'pages#mission', :as => :mission`

So shouldn't I be able to break that first line down into

`match 'practice_areas/pet_planning' => 'pet_planning#index', :as => :pet_planning`

`match 'practice_areas/pet_planning2' => 'pet_planning2#index', :as => :pet_planning2`

etc.. ?

Comment: Yeah, you're on the right track. See my edited answer for the correct routes. Note also that there might be a better way to do it, I've added a suggestion at the bottom :)

Answer (score 0):

The render calls in pet_planning, mission, and disclaimer do the same as default behavior, so those calls can be removed.  They are telling rails to use the pages with the given file names.  For the index method, this is rendering a page based on a parameter.

The title and description are likely set in the layout.  Look in /views/layouts/application.html.haml or /views/layouts/pages.html.haml.